# Double nested Array in JSON leads to TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, strapi

In my code I try to get to the 2 thumbnail urls in the JSON below. I'm only able to get in the first Array the

```
<>{post.attributes.description}</>
```

but I'm not able to get in the second array the

```
<>{img.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url}</>
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

  11 | <div key={post.id}>
  12 |   <>{post.attributes.description}</>
> 13 |   {post.attributes.image["data"].map((img) => (
     |                                 ^
  14 |     <div key={img.id}>
  15 |       <>{img.attributes.name}</>
  16 |     </div>
```

Code

```
import React from "react";

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts["data"].map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <>{post.attributes.description}</>
          {post.attributes.image["data"].map((img) => (
            <div key={img.id}>
              <>{img.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url}</>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/games?populate=*");
  const posts = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "gw2",
        "description": "test",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-18T21:11:17.405Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-20T16:39:07.188Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-18T21:11:18.345Z",
        "image": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "attributes": {
                "name": "ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                "alternativeText": "ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                "caption": "ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080,
                "formats": {
                  "thumbnail": {
                    "name": "thumbnail_ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "thumbnail_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 245,
                    "height": 138,
                    "size": 7.88,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c.jpg"
                  },
                  "large": {
                    "name": "large_ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "large_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 1000,
                    "height": 563,
                    "size": 80.97,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/large_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c.jpg"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                    "name": "medium_ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "medium_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 750,
                    "height": 422,
                    "size": 49.54,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/medium_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c.jpg"
                  },
                  "small": {
                    "name": "small_ddda8Screenshot-02-EfLA-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "small_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 500,
                    "height": 281,
                    "size": 25.21,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/small_ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c.jpg"
                  }
                },
                "hash": "ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "size": 258.19,
                "url": "/uploads/ddda8_Screenshot_02_Ef_LA_1920x1080_9e7cc15b9c.jpg",
                "previewUrl": null,
                "provider": "local",
                "provider_metadata": null,
                "createdAt": "2022-02-20T16:37:41.604Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-02-20T16:37:41.604Z"
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "attributes": {
                "name": "76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                "alternativeText": "76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                "caption": "76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080,
                "formats": {
                  "thumbnail": {
                    "name": "thumbnail_76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "thumbnail_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 245,
                    "height": 138,
                    "size": 10.28,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0.jpg"
                  },
                  "large": {
                    "name": "large_76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "large_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 1000,
                    "height": 563,
                    "size": 113.82,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/large_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0.jpg"
                  },
                  "medium": {
                    "name": "medium_76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "medium_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 750,
                    "height": 422,
                    "size": 70.06,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/medium_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0.jpg"
                  },
                  "small": {
                    "name": "small_76ade04-Flame-Frost-Dyes-1920x1080.jpg",
                    "hash": "small_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "width": 500,
                    "height": 281,
                    "size": 34.66,
                    "path": null,
                    "url": "/uploads/small_76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0.jpg"
                  }
                },
                "hash": "76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "size": 348.37,
                "url": "/uploads/76ade04_Flame_Frost_Dyes_1920x1080_749230faa0.jpg",
                "previewUrl": null,
                "provider": "local",
                "provider_metadata": null,
                "createdAt": "2022-02-20T16:37:41.616Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-02-20T16:37:41.616Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "game2 ",
        "description": "jkgbr",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.108Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.967Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.965Z",
        "image": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "game3",
        "description": "sqlekjlbkgt",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-18T21:16:18.886Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-18T21:16:19.996Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-18T21:16:19.995Z",
        "image": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "game 4",
        "description": "sadjglklasdhbl",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-19T06:25:06.589Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-19T06:25:07.300Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-19T06:25:07.297Z",
        "image": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "game 5 notebook",
        "description": "create on notebook",
        "createdAt": "2022-02-19T06:46:04.335Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-19T06:46:05.471Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-02-19T06:46:05.469Z",
        "image": {
          "data": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody help a total JS newbie on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your data.  Most of the "post" records have this:

```
"image": {
  "data": null
}
```

The `data` value *is null*.  So when you do this:

```
post.attributes.image["data"].map(...)
```

You are trying to call `.map()` on `null`.  Which is what the error is telling you:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
```

If the value might be `null`, check for `null` before using it.  For example:

```
post.attributes.image["data"]?.map(...)
```

Or more explicitly:

```
post.attributes.image["data"] ?
  post.attributes.image["data"].map(...) :
  null
```

Basically any time you have an object/array that might be `null`, you need to make sure that it *isn't* `null` before trying to de-reference it.

In this case I'm assuming that you don't want the code to produce any output when it encounters a `null` value.  If that's not the case then you can conditionally produce whatever output you like when you encounter a `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that in one of your entries in image.data are with a null entry. Check the second entry with id `2`.

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "attributes": {
    "title": "game2 ",
    "description": "jkgbr",
    "createdAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.108Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.967Z",
    "publishedAt": "2022-02-18T21:12:12.965Z",
    "image": {
      "data": null
    }
  }
},
```

When map tries to read the entire array of images in each post, if it finds a null entry it will break. Something that helps is using the `optional chaining operator "?."` in JS. This prevents that if an null or undefined has been found by Array.map it will not break the entire React render.

```
{post.attributes.image?.["data"]?.map((img) => ())}
```

Comment: also thanks to you this does the job!